# Compiler error when using Info-ZIP 3.0 source code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, zip

In our legacy C++ code base, we are using Info-ZIP 3.0 source code (written in C) available from https://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/Zip%203.x%20%28latest%29/3.0/ to create
ZIP-files.  Switching to another framework for ZIP-file creation is currently
not an option due to time constraints.  To use this code, we do something like

```
extern "C" {
  #include "api.h"
}
...
extern "C" int EXPENTRY ZpArchive(ZCL C, LPZPOPT Opts);
```

This has worked well with VS2015, but it no longer compiles when switching to
VS2019.  The problem is that Info-ZIP's `api.h` includes Info-ZIP's `zip.h`, which has the following define:

```
  #define CR     13
```

later on, `api.h` also conditionally includes `windows.h`:

```
#if defined(WINDLL) || defined(API)
#include <windows.h>
...
#endif /* WINDLL? || API? */
```

which eventually also includes `winnt.h` which has the following typedef:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_ARM64_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY {
    DWORD BeginAddress;
    union {
        DWORD UnwindData;
        struct {
            DWORD Flag : 2;
            DWORD FunctionLength : 11;
            DWORD RegF : 3;
            DWORD RegI : 4;
            DWORD H : 1;
            DWORD CR : 2;
            DWORD FrameSize : 9;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
} IMAGE_ARM64_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY, * PIMAGE_ARM64_RUNTIME_FUNCTION_ENTRY;
```

Note that the `CR` member in the inner struct from this typedef conflicts with
the previously defined CR macro, and this gives a compiler error.

What would be a clean way to solve this, preferably without changing Info-ZIP's source code too much (or even nothing at all)?

Comment: Can you shift the contents of `api.h` around? Move the definition of `CR` below the `winnt.h` include? Remove the CR definition altogether?

Comment: Note that I can solve the compiler error by renaming the `CR` macro (to for example `INFOZIP_CR`), but as I prefer to keep modifications to third party code as minimal as possible, I am wondering if there exists a solution for which I don't need to change Info-ZIP's code.

Comment: Will this work: `#include "zip.h"`, `#undef CR`, `#include "api.h"`?

Comment: You're in control of the source code, so you can just replace all occurences of `CR` with say `MYCR`. The impact is small.

Comment: @BartVandewoestyne Compile with `-UCR -DINFOZIP_CR=16 -DCR=INFOZIP_CR`

Answer (score 1):

I finally decided to solve the problem by renaming the CR macro to INFOZIP_CR.  It turned out I had to do that only in four places, so the impact on the Info-ZIP source code is rather minimal.  Thanks for all the comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if there exists a solution for which I don't need to change Info-ZIP's code.

Provided that `windows.h` has an include guard, a solution could be to include it first:

```
#include <windows.h>
extern "C"
{
  #include "api.h"
}
```

This way, the `struct` definition is parsed before the `#define CR` gets in the way. Of course, this only works if the `CR` element of the `struct` is not used later in the compilation unit.